# How to customize position of checkboxes, drop down list, etc. in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, position, tkinter-layout

[I want to achieve the exact appearance of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJalR.png)

I want to learn how to position the tickboxes, checkbox, dropdown menu, and menu list that exactly looks like the image that I have inserted. I do not know the syntax on how to write the positioning of each

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

windows = Tk()
gender = ["male", "female"]
sport = ["Cricket", "Tennis"]
numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

windows.title("Hello Python")
windows.geometry("350x300")

x = IntVar(windows)
for index in range(len(gender)):
    radiobutton = Radiobutton(windows,
                              text=gender[index],
                              variable=x,
                              value=index,)
    radiobutton.pack(side=LEFT,ipadx=10,ipady=10)


for index in range(len(sport)):
    checkboxgui = Checkbutton(windows,
                               text=sport[index], onvalue=1,
                               offvalue=0)

    checkboxgui.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

clicked = StringVar(windows)
clicked.set("one")
drop = ttk.Combobox(windows, textvariable=clicked,values=numbers)
drop.pack()

listbox = Listbox(windows,selectmode=MULTIPLE)
listbox.pack()
listbox.insert(1,"one")
listbox.insert(2,"two")
listbox.insert(3,"three")
listbox.insert(4,"four")
listbox.config(height=listbox.size())



windows.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know how to achieve something like your picture is by organizing the interactive widgets into frames and then `pack()` them individually so that you can follow the logic the packer will use. But I did set an approximate size like your example.  Notice that in order to get your `Combobox`to align at the top I had to use the `expand` and `fill` parameter. It would be beneficial for you to look at something like [this](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-pack/). For a nice explanation with examples for how the `pack()` method works. I did not prevent the user from expanding the window, so you could still maximize the window beyond what you showed in your picture.  I hope this helps.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x300")

x = tk.IntVar()
numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

radio_frame = tk.Frame(window)
radio_frame.pack(ipady=30)

male_radio = tk.Radiobutton(radio_frame, text="male", variable=x)
male_radio.pack(side="left")

female_radio = tk.Radiobutton(radio_frame, text="female", variable=x)
female_radio.pack(side="left")

check_frame = tk.Frame(window)
check_frame.pack(ipady=10)

check_button1 = tk.Checkbutton(check_frame, text="Cricket", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
check_button1.pack(side="left")

check_button2 = tk.Checkbutton(check_frame, text="Tennis", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
check_button2.pack(side="left")

bottom_frame = tk.Frame(window)
bottom_frame.pack(pady=20)

drop_frame = tk.Frame(bottom_frame)
drop_frame.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set("one")

drop = ttk.Combobox(drop_frame, textvariable=clicked, values=numbers)
drop.pack()

list_frame = tk.Frame(bottom_frame)
list_frame.pack(side="left")

listbox = tk.Listbox(list_frame,selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
listbox.pack(padx=40, ipady=10)

listbox.insert(1,"one")
listbox.insert(2,"two")
listbox.insert(3,"three")
listbox.insert(4,"four")
listbox.config(height=listbox.size())

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you, may I know how to make the male and female only tick one ? if i click it, both of them are ticked....

Comment: you would add a `value` parameter to the radio button and since you set the `variable` to `tk.IntVar()` just assign them different integer values.  For the male radio button it would look like this: `male_radio = tk.Radiobutton(radio_frame, text="male", variable=x, value=1)`. Then the same for the female except with a value of 2 for example.